# How to make replica of a javascript class method?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript class

```
class A {
  methodA (){
    //doing some operations with arguments
  }
  methodB (){ // i need to refer this function to `returns` function
  }
  // i am expecting something like below
  methodB : A.methods.methodA 
  // NOT like below
  methodB (...args){
    return this.methodA(...args);
  }
}
```

Any idea about the simplest way to make replica of a method in javascript class?

EDIT: Also please give some solution, if methodA and methodB would be some `static` methods.

Comment: If im correct `return` keyword is [reserved](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp).

Comment: @JanCiołek updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could copy them outside of the class e.g:

```
class A{
 returns(){
 }
 static returns(){
 }
}

A.sth=A.returns;
A.prototype.sth=A.prototype.returns;
```

You could also bind in the constructor:

```
class A {
 constructor(){
  this.sth=this.returns.bind(this);
 }
 returns (){
//doing some operations with arguments
 }
}

(new A).sth()
```

Or you could add two pointers to a global function (not yet possible with class syntax):

```
function returns(){
  return true;
}

function A(){}
A.prototype={
 returns:returns,
 sth:returns
};
//static:
Object.assign(A,{
 returns:returns,
 sth:returns
});

(new A).sth();
(new A).returns();
A.sth();
A.returns();
```

Comment: nice approach, Any idea if methodA and methodB would be static method of class?

Comment: @codeofnode class syntax is not really useful yet in JS. I hope that the class property proposal becomes part of the spec soon (makes stuff like this more easy). The old way function constructor syntax supports static methods too, so the second code would work too with static props...